Navbar is not fixed to bottom on mobile
I have a Navbar thats on the bottom of the site on mobile.
For some reason it's not fixed to the Bottom and moves when i scroll.
It's only a little gap but it is really annoying to look at.

My Css looks like this:
.navbar{
    position: fixed;
    background-color: var(--bg-secondary);
    transition: width 175ms ease;
    z-index: 999;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 980px) and (min-width: 368px) {
    .navbar{
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100vw;
        height: 3.7rem;
        margin-left: -0.5rem;
    }
}

Funny enough when using the mobile inspector on Desktop chrome or firefox it does stay fixed. It has to be a problem with mobile browser.
Tried it on Chrome, Firefox and Samsung Internet
Has anyone expirienced a similar problem?
Minimal production example:


@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,700&display=swap);
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,700&display=swap);
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,700&display=swap);
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,700&display=swap);
:root {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  --text-primary: #ffffff;
  --text-secondary: #9d9d9d;
  --accent-color: #cc9933;
  --lighter-accent-color: #d0ab2f;
  --bg-primary: #18191b;
  --bg-secondary: #1d2125;
  --bg-tertiary: #181818;
  --transition-speed: 500ms;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.navbar {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: var(--bg-secondary);
  transition: width 175ms ease;
  z-index: 999;
}

.navbar_nav {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
}

.nav_item {
  width: 100%;
}

.testContainer{
  height: 900vh;
  background-color: var(--accent-color);
}

.nav_link {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  color: var(--text-primary);
  text-decoration: none;

  transition: var(--transition-speed);
}

.svg {
  fill: var(--accent-color);
}

.link_text {
  display: none;
  margin-left: 1rem;
}

.nav_link:hover {
  color: var(--lighter-accent-color);
  filter: grayscale(0%) opacity(1);
}

.logo {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  color: var(--text-secondary);
  background: var(--bg-primary);
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  letter-spacing: 0.3ch;
  width: 100%;
}

.logo svg {
  transition: var(--transition-speed);
}

.logo-text {
  display: inline;
  position: absolute;
  left: -999px;
  transition: var(--transition-speed);
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 980px) and (min-width: 368px) {
  .navbar {
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 3.7rem;
    margin-left: -0.5rem;
  }

  .logo {
    display: none;
  }

  .navbar_nav {
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
  }

  .nav_link {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100%;
    color: var(--accent-color);
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  main {
    margin: 0;
    margin-bottom: 4rem;
  }

  .nav_link svg {
    width: 1.4rem;
    min-width: 1rem;
    margin: 0 1.5rem;
  }

  .link_text {
    display: flex;
    font-size: 11px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }

  #ab_svg {
    width: 1.5rem;
  }

  .about {
    margin-bottom: -0.17rem;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 390px) {
  .navbar {
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 3rem;
    margin-left: -0.5rem;
  }

  .logo {
    display: none;
  }

  .navbar_nav {
    flex-direction: row;
  }

  .nav_link {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100%;
    color: var(--accent-color);
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-left: -0.3rem;
  }

  main {
    margin: 0;
    margin-bottom: 1.9rem;
  }

  .nav_link svg {
    width: 1rem;
    min-width: 0.4rem;
  }

  #ab_svg {
    width: 1.3rem;
  }

  .link_text {
    display: flex;
    font-size: 9px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 981px) {
  .navbar {
    top: 0;
    width: 5rem;
    height: 100vh;
    margin-left: -0.5rem;
  }

  .nav_link {
    height: 5rem;
    filter: grayscale(100%) opacity(0.7);
  }

  .navbar:hover {
    width: 14rem;
  }
  .navbar:hover .link_text {
    display: inline;
    transition: opacity var(--transition-speed);
  }

  .nav_item:last-child {
    margin-top: auto;
  }

  .nav_link svg {
    width: 2rem;
    min-width: 2rem;
    margin: 0 1.5rem;
  }
}
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Navbar Example</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <nav class="navbar">
      <ul class="navbar_nav">
        <li class="logo">
          <a href="/" class="nav_link">
            <!-- SVG for Start -->
            <span class="link_text">TEst</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav_item">
          <a href="/" class="nav_link">
            <!-- SVG for Start -->
            <span class="link_text">Start</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav_item">
          <a href="/training" class="nav_link">
            <!-- SVG for Training -->
            <span class="link_text">Training</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav_item">
          <a href="/about" class="nav_link about">
            <!-- SVG for Über uns -->
            <span class="link_text">Über uns</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav_item">
          <a href="/gallery" class="nav_link">
            <!-- SVG for Bildgalerie -->
            <span class="link_text">Bildgalerie</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav_item">
          <a href="/contact" class="nav_link">
            <!-- SVG for Kontakt -->
            <span class="link_text">Kontakt</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav_item">
          <a href="/eventhub" class="nav_link">
            <!-- SVG for Events -->
            <span class="link_text">Events</span>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  
  <div class="testContainer">
     TEst
  </div>
</body>

</html>



This might have something to do with this: CSS3 100vh not constant in mobile browser 
But it doesnt really solve the problem when the position is fixed and set to bottom: 0

moves when I scroll - Can you add an element to your snippets so the page will be scrollable, and we will be able to see the behavior you are describing?"

@TamirAbutbul Updated it. Hope it can assist in helping me

I tried this on my phone and it is perfectly stuck at the bottom of then screen and does not move at all. It appears there is a little "line" though but this is coming from the soft button of your/my phone. Tested on Chrome on Google Pixel 7 Pro

@makkusu ok thats weird. So probably just an issue on my phone?
